# ISO 8859 1 octal back to normal characters

Tags: php, laravel, encoding

I'm currently converting our old project database into a new format/new database. There are some old data, which were probably escaped by a smartphone app. Now the entry looks like this:

```
Tak hur\341 v posteli po pr\341ci a jde se sp\355nkat
```

now the real entry should look like this:

```
Tak hurá v posteli po práci a jde se spinkat
```

There are also entries like

```
Som nen\\355 ja len chodiaca kapuc\\341 pra\\u0161iva ignorujuca
```

which don't seem like ISO 8859 1, especially the `\\u0161` part.

Any thoughts on any PHP function I may use to convert this back to readable version? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple workaround:

The first string is only octal iso-8859-1, while the second one is double slashed iso-8859-1 with mixed utf-16 characters (why? now that is the question). The code below takes octal codes, converts to hex, packs them to binary and encodes them into utf-8. The utf-16 codes are already in hex, so they are only packed and encoded into utf-8.

For future info reference on charsets: http://www.fileformat.info/info/charset/index.htm

```
<?php
        $string = "Tak hur\341 v posteli po pr\341ci a jde se sp\355nkat";
        $string2 = "Som nen\\355 ja len chodiaca kapuc\\341 pra\\u0161iva ignorujuca";

        print decode_str($string2)."<br>";
        print decode_str($string);


        function decode_str($string){
            return utf16_to_utf8(iso_to_utf8($string));
        }

        function iso_to_utf8($string){
            preg_match_all('#\\\\[0-9]{3}#',$string,$matches);

            foreach($matches[0] as $match){
                $char = preg_replace("#(\\\)#","",$match);
                $a = pack("H*" , base_convert($char,8,16));
                $string = preg_replace('#(\\\\)'.$char.'#',$a,$string);
            }
            return mb_convert_encoding($string,"UTF-8","ISO-8859-1");   
        }

        function utf16_to_utf8($string){
            preg_match_all('#\\\u[a-z0-9]{4}#',$string,$matches);

            foreach($matches[0] as $match){
                $char = preg_replace("#\\\\u#","",$match);
                $a = pack("H*" , $char);
                $a = mb_convert_encoding($a,"UTF-8","UTF-16");
                $string = preg_replace('#'.preg_quote($match).'#',$a,$string);
            }

            return $string;
        }

    ?>
```

Comment: Slight change (as noted by the author of the question): preg_match_all in utf16_to_utf8 function should have u[a-f0-9], as utf uses hex numbers.